# Admin/people/create not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Drupal `admin/people/create` is rendering the form but when I try to submit the form it redirects to the same path admin/people/create shows the content of admin/people path (just a user listing without add user button).

I'm user 1 and have permission "administer users".
No custom submit handlers on the form.
But the form itself is altered and new fields were added. I know that it could be done from the admin interface, but that's how the project is written.

Note: No other user-related modules in repo

Any idea how to solve this problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for the drupal support community and not related to programming.

Comment: What alterations have you made to the form? You've probably added, removed or overwritten something that was required for the form to work.

Comment: I solved the problem by commenting custom code.